# Is the word order important in the phrase "мы тоже ее видим"?

Tags: порядок-слов

What is the difference between the phrases:

> Мы тоже ее видим

and

> Мы видим ее тоже

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question? Again, there's no context in your question. No context = no answer and closed question.

Comment: **Мы тоже ее видим**. Here **тоже** is related to **мы**. Others see her (it) and we see her (it) too.

Comment: **Мы видим ее тоже.**  Here **тоже** is related to **её.** We see a lot of different things and we see her(it) too

Comment: @Elena - It's all context-dependent. Here's context in which **тоже** is related to **мы** or to the whole sentence, but *no*t to **ee** in **Мы видим ее тоже** (“We, too, see her/it”): _Командир: «Кто из вас видит цель?» Отряд 1: «Мы не видим ее». Отряд 2: «Мы видим ее». Отряд 3: «Мы видим ее тоже»._

Comment: In general - not important. No more than others cases with order of words in Russian

Comment: @YellowSky, If you were writing a book (i.e. had no other way to convey all the connotations other than by plain text), wouldn't it be more natural for Squad 3 to say: "Мы тоже видим её."?

Comment: @IgorG - It is irrelevant what would be natural to say in that situation. I just showed the context in which Elena's statement about “Мы видим ее тоже” is wrong. But generally speaking, in the army they say the most important information first, then secondary remarks. Here “we can see” / “we cannot see” is of primary importance, “too” is secondary, so it wouldn't be natural for the military to say “Мы тоже видим её.”

Comment: @YellowSky, have a heart! :- ) Not every native speaker has military background and follows military reporting rules :- ) FYI: in the world of technical writers, it's exactly the other way round: sentence must start with known information, and new information (the key!) must come second. P.S. I wish Elena had posted her opinion as an answer. I would support it.

Comment: @IgorG - That sentence does start with known information, the theme, it is _мы_. Then goes the most important new information, the rheme, _видим / не видим_.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very thinly nuanced distinction.

Without commas or other punctuation, the word closer to the beginning gets greater emphasis. In this case, "Мы тоже ее видим" can be translated as "Just like you, we can see it", while "Мы видим ее тоже" - "We can see it, just like you".

Comment: Why have you used that “just like _you_” in your translations. Whom do you mean by “_you_”? Why not “just like them” or “just like her”?

Comment: @Yellow Sky I am sorry, I did not intend to provide a generic translation here, only an example based on presumed context. In a specific context, it indeed can be "her", or "him", or "them".

Comment: It would be a lot more common to use "Мы её тоже видим" instead if "We can see it/her, just like you" was intended. "Мы видим её тоже" is more akin to "We can see it/her [as well as something else we see]".

Answer (score 1):

The second variant has an unmarked word order and is thus neutral.

«Тоже» in the first variant, jumps out of the unmarked word order and thus gets emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

- Мы тоже ее видим = вы её видите, и мы тоже её видим, как и вы;
- Мы видим ее тоже = мы видим её среди других; мы видим не одну её, но других тоже видим.

*Google translate:*

- Мы тоже ее видим = you see it, and we see it too, just like you;
- Мы видим ее тоже = we see her among others; we see not only one of them, but we also see others.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133781/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid-is-the-word-order-important-in-the-phrase--).

Answer (score 1):

Well... I'm posting this answer because I feel that each of existing answers tells only part of the story.

Technically (with a certain amount of imagination), each of the sentences you're asking about could be interpreted as either of the following:

- "**We** see her, too", where "too" means "just like you do".
- "We see **her** too", where "too" means "just like we see someone else".

How does one tell which interpretation is the most plausible?

1. In live speech, **intonation stress** will emphasize the semantic center of the sentence. "Too" should be linked to that center then. Intonation is a strong indicator; it can override all other criteria.
2. Without intonation (that is, if all we have is a written text), **context** is the next most important thing to consider.
3. Without context (that is, in a standalone phrase like in your question), **word order** is all that is left to suggest the right interpretation.

So your question boils down to interpreting the word order...

It is true that word order isn't that important in Russian; inflection may help you glean the meaning even from an extremely scrambled sentence. However, there are limits: certain invariable words can form collocations with almost any other word. So as you drag such a word across the sentence, it will "snap" semantically to the nearest word, potentially creating different meanings. Take, for example, amplifying words like "именно", "точно" ("exactly, precisely"):

- "**Именно** я видел её." =~ "It was **me** who saw her."
- "Я **именно** видел её." =~ "**Seeing** her was what I did."
- "Я видел **именно** её." =~ "It was **her** that I saw."

"**Тоже**" is one of those words: it can form a semantic bond with many different words. Hence the technical ambiguity of its interpretation.
It may be just my personal opinion, but in this particular case it seems natural to me to link "тоже" with the preceding pronoun. So to answer your question:

> What is the difference between the phrases

"Мы тоже её видим" becomes "We see her, just like you do".
"Мы видим её тоже" becomes "We see her, along with other people/things".

---

Edit:
To my taste, that last sentence sounds a bit broken. It begs for an "и": "Мы видим и её тоже".

If it was me writing those sentences and I wanted to disambiguate the semantic stress even in writing, I would have put unstressed "и" before the emphasized word in all the sentences:
"И мы тоже её видим".
"Мы и видим её тоже".
"Мы видим и её тоже".
That would've eliminated any possible doubts regarding what word "тоже" is linked to.

Answer (score -2):

В такой записи разницы нет никакой, в действительности.
В русском языке порядок слов сам по себе не важен, как в языке - флективно-синтетическом.

Любая такая фраза приобретает то или иное смысловое ударение и различия - лишь благодаря фонетической интонации и контексту.

1. Мы тоже **её** видим = Мы видим **её** тоже - именно её, а не другой объект.
2. Мы тоже её **видим** = Мы **видим** её тоже - именно видим,а не слышим, например...
3. **Мы** тоже её видим = **Мы** видим её тоже - именно мы, а не кто-то еще.

Но 1. и 2. и 3. не равны друг другу, не в точности, есть акцентация на выделенном слове. :>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133780/discussion-on-answer-by--is-the-word-order-important-in-the-phrase--).

Comment: -1, поскольку считаю утверждение в первом абзаце чрезмерно обобщённым. В русском языке далеко не все слова имеют флексию. И вот как раз неизменяемые слова могут придавать предложению разный смысл в зависимости от своей позиции.

Comment: "не все имеют флексию" - а какая разница ? ну 1% может и не имеет, всякие там иностранные не склоняемые...  язык все равно флективный именно :>  
Вы их не распознаете как части речи по сей причине и требуется дополнительная морфология и правила ? Нет вроде. Несущественно. :>
В аналитическом (англ. например) зачем строгий порядок нужен вообще - они части речи не распознают. :>
Как и без артиклей :>

Comment: Igor G... "И вот как раз неизменяемые слова могут... разн.смысл" - это что-то настолько редкое... :>> "Мы тоже видим Сюзен"... "Мы Сюзен видим тоже"... без разницы... тоже :> Они еще и существительные по большей части-то, по крайней мере, что уже сужает вариации

Comment: а что касается "именно" и там всяких "тоже" - так дело не в том, что они несклоняемы - а в том, что это семантическая уже акцентация и это функция этого слова абстрактная и управляющая, но на самом деле привязка сего от позиции ничуть не зависит. ;>> "я ЕЁ видел именно" - во всяком случае, фонетическая интонация и контекст имеют ясный приоритет, а даже если образуются такие "пары слов" как "именно её" - ну и что ? :> все равно их можно переставлять как угодно уже парами, это еще не "порядок"

Comment: и на самом деле склоняемы для "то же", "те же", "тех же". ;>Ясен перец финист сокол : "то же" и "тоже", оформлено ли оно "грамматеями" так или эдак, а одно и то же...  :> "же", "ли" - несклоняемы, да. Ну и что... :>